# Find the optimal order of matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, algorithms, computer-science

Suppose that $n$ matrices have dimensions $1 \times 1, 1 \times d, d \times 1, or \space d \times d$. Design an algorithm to find the optimal order to multiply them.

---

My approach is to *minimize* the dimension of resulting matrix. for example, $d \times d$ matrix times another $d \times d$ matrix will have an $O(n^3)$.
Therefore, if there's a $d \times d$ matrix, always multiplies it with a $d \times 1$ or $1 \times d$ matrix. If there are pairs of $1 \times d$ and $d \times 1$, make them multiply.

Is it my approach practicable?

Comment: Why don't you Google first : you will find for example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication)

Comment: It seems you also would need to think about avoiding being left with just $d\times d$ and $1\times 1$ matrices, which cannot be multiplied.

Comment: @ j0equ1nn I think $d \times d$ and $1 \times 1$ can be multiplied. I tried this with matlab

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic problem with introduction to dynamic programming. [Corn, Leicerson and Rivest](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262033844) analyze this in depth in Section 15.2.

Comment: I have learned that chapter in class, but don't quite understand what this problem ask for. I mean, if the matrix chain multiplication can solve the general case. Why this problem asks a specific case?